# Gnuplot imprime valores negativos que no existen

Tags: gnuplot

Estoy sacando unas gráficas a partir de un sencillo fichero csv. El problema es que, por alguna razón, en la gráfica aparecen valores negativos que en el CSV no existen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podéis ver en la imagen, hay valores que están por debajo de cero, repito, estos valores no existen en el csv.

Sin embargo, utilizando esta herramienta online https://chart-studio.plotly.com/create/#/ obtengo esta gráfica:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Donde efectivamente, no hay ningun valor por debajo de 0.

Es la primera vez que utilizo GNUPlot y no sé muy bien que es lo que ocurre, tampoco he encontrado nada al respecto sobre este "bug", por llamarlo de alguna manera.

Este es el código que estoy utilizando en GNUPlot:

```
set terminal postscript eps color
set output "tJumpPerFrame.eps"
set key right bottom
set xlabel "Frame"
set ylabel "T Jump"
set yrange [0:0.05]
set datafile separator ","
plot 'tJumpPerFrame.csv' using 1:2 t "Mono" w l
```